# Android: Using array adapter to display a list array

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm not getting a direct error in Eclipse.. but when trying to run this on my phone it doesn't open the activity and then my phone resets. I might be using the array adapter wrong.. but here's my code files:

Java File
        package creativecoders.periodictable;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    public class AM extends Activity {

        private ListView amList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.am);

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.AM, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            amList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            finish();
        }

        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            finish();
        }

        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            finish();
        }

    }
```

XML Layout File

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

String File

```
      <string-array name="AM">
        <item>  ONE  </item>
        <item>  TWO  </item>
        <item>  THREE  </item>
      </string-array>
```

EDIT: Log file:
04-20 23:10:07.660: D/AndroidRuntime(284): Shutting down VM
04-20 23:10:07.660: W/dalvikvm(284): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{creativecoders.periodictable/creativecoders.periodictable.AM}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at creativecoders.periodictable.AM.onStart(AM.java:28)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3781)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
04-20 23:10:07.670: E/AndroidRuntime(284):  ... 11 more

Comment: You have to also post your error stack/log. Connect your phone to computer and run "adb logcat *:E" in terminal to check what's the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not initialize the ListView. in onCreate()

```
amList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much, I can't believe I passed that up. You rock! :-)